# Will Count(*) on unique index stop after 1 record found?

Tags: count, exists, sap-ase

I have inherited some dodgy looking SQL which, when looking for a row with a unique index,  uses `COUNT(*) = 1` instead of using `EXISTS`

I know I'm being optimistic but will the query be smart enough to stop counting rows if its looking for a unique index and it finds a record?

I have tried to test this and it seems that the answer is no, but I was looking for a definitive answer before beginning the process of changing this code.

We use Sybase ASE 15.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the answer is yes.

I did a query plan analysis and it stated:

```
  Forward Scan.
  Positioning by key.
  Index contains all needed columns. Base table will not be read.
```

Actually this seems clear now as the query will obviously use the index and then the aggregate is simply counting the result of that query.